# innerHTML not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get an error message where if the user types the username or password wrong, a message pops up underneath the sign in box saying they got it wrong. but for some reason, it's not showing up. does anyone know why?

here is my code

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
      apiClient.signIn(username, password) .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response)

        if (response === 'Logged In') {          
        return <Redirect to='/forum' />
      }
       else {
         return document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Wrong Username or Password"
       }
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error found when creating meeting');
      })

      
    }
    
       
      return (
        <section class="index-banner">
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Grid container style = {{minHeight: '100vh'}} spacing={0}  direction="column"  alignItems="center">
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>

                <div className = "title-2">Sign In</div>
                <div>
                  <FormControl margin = "normal">
                    <TextField label="Username" value = {username} onChange={e => { getUser(e.target.value) }} spacing={4} />    
                    <TextField label="Password" value = {password} onChange={e => { getPass(e.target.value) }} spacing={4}/>
                   
                  </FormControl>
                </div>                 
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                  <Button onClick={onSubmit} variant="contained" component="span" spacing={4} color = "secondary">
                    Sign In
                  </Button>
               </Grid> 
               <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                  <Button component = {Link} to = "/" spacing={4} color = "primary">
                     Create Account
                  </Button>
                   <div className="error"></div>
               </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </ThemeProvider>      
        </section>         
      )
```

Comment: Where is the innerHTML property in your code?

Comment: For starters, you are targeting an ID, but that div does not have an ID value of "error", it has the class "error."

Comment: @AndrewL64 I forgot to remove the .value, I edited the post now

Answer (score 0):

`value` is only used or form elements like `input` or `textarea` etc...

#### The else statement should be either `innerHTML` or `textContent`:

```
. . .
else {
  return document.getElementById('error').textContent = "Wrong Username or Password"
}
. . .
```

OR

```
. . .
else {
  return document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Wrong Username or Password"
}
. . .
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change it, it was originally ```innerHTML``` which wasn't working so I tried ```.value``` next. I just forgot to switch it for this question. But as for your question, textContect didn't work for me either

Comment: @AmmanM Then you should go with `@ChristianFritz` answer.

Answer (score 0):

In React you should avoid modifying the DOM directly. The typical way of accomplishing what you want, is to use a state variable for the error message.

```
const [error, setError] = useState('');

const onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  apiClient.signIn(username, password).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)  
    if (response === 'Logged In') {
      return <Redirect to='/forum' />
    }
    else {
      setError("Wrong Username or Password");
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('Error found when creating meeting');
  })
}

return (
  <section class="index-banner">
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container style = {{minHeight: '100vh'}} spacing={0}  direction="column"  alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
        
          <div className = "title-2">Sign In</div>
          <div>
            <FormControl margin = "normal">
              <TextField label="Username" value = {username} onChange={e => { getUser(e.target.value) }} spacing={4} />    
              <TextField label="Password" value = {password} onChange={e => { getPass(e.target.value) }} spacing={4}/>
              
            </FormControl>
          </div>                 
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
            <Button onClick={onSubmit} variant="contained" component="span" spacing={4} color = "secondary">
              Sign In
            </Button>
          </Grid> 
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
            <Button component = {Link} to = "/" spacing={4} color = "primary">
              Create Account
            </Button>
            <div className="error">{error}</div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>      
  </section>         
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunately this answer didn't work for me as well.

Comment: the message in the innerHTML still didn't show up. Maybe it has to do with the way I laid out the site? I will try to check it out